# Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $Y \subset \mathbf{A}^n$ be the set $\{(t,t^2,t^3|t \in k\}$. What is are the gnerators of $I(Y)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm having a problem thinking through this rigorously.
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $Y \subset \mathbf{A}^n$ be the set $\{(t,t^2,t^3|t \in k\}$. What is are the generators of $I(Y)$?

I know that $I(Y) = \{f \in A|f(P) = 0, \forall P \in Y\}$, so that $I(Y)$ is the ideal of polynomials $f$ such that $f$ has $P$ as a root for all $P \in Y$. I am trouble showing that $I(Y)$ is the ideal generated by $y-x^2$ and $z-x^3$. Intuitively i see that $I(Y) = \bigcap_{t \in k} (x-t,y-t^2,z-t^3)$, but I do not remember a way to say this is in fact $(y-x^2,z-x^3)$. Any suggestions would be helpful I believe that I am just forgetting some properties of ideals.

Comment: Oh, hmm. I might've been thinking of a higher-degree example.

Answer (score 1):

Surely $y-x^2, z-x^3 \in I(Y)$. Let $I= \langle y-x^2, z-x^3 \rangle $, let $f(x,y,z) \in I(Y)$ so we have $f(t,t^2,t^3)=0$ for any $t \in k$ or $g(x) = f(x,x^2,x^3) \equiv 0 $ since $g(t)=0$ for all $t \in k$. We will now show $f(x,y,z) + I = 0+I$ which will do the job. $f(x,y,z) + I = f(x,x^2,x^3)+I = 0 +I$. Hence $I = I (Y)$.

Comment: Just to clarify are we actually saying $g(x) = f(x,x^2,x^3) = 0$ as $g(x)$ is a polynomial in one variable that must have infinitely many solutions because $k$ is algebraically closed implies that its cardinality is infinite. The only polynomials that have infinitely many solutions in one variable are the constant polynomials, in this case it would then have to be the zero polynomial.

Comment: That's right, thanks for the clarification.